# Method Range of object_worksheet failed 1004

Tags: excel, vba, range

I wrote some code which works perfectly as it should when I debug it. But when I remove the breakpoint and just run the code, it give a runtime error:

runtime error '1004'
Method Range of object_worksheet failed.

It refers to  the next line:

```
Set copyrange = sh.Range("A" & i & ":E" & i & ",I" & i & ":O" & i & ",Q" & i & ",V" & i) 'name column in sheet  = Q
```

But while debugging it, there isn't a problem. Maybe the cache is full?

```
Private Sub btnGetDevices_Click()
'open every sheet after summary
'copy columns A,B,C,D,E,I,J,K,L,M,N,O, Q,V to summary

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim copyrange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Summary").Rows(4 & ":" & Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count).Delete
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> "Database" And sh.Name <> "Template" And sh.Name <> "Help" And sh.Name <> "OVERVIEW" And sh.Name <> "Develop" And sh.Name <> "Schedule" And sh.Name <> "Information" And sh.Name <> "Announcements" And sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
        sh.Select
        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("L1048555").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 14 To LastRow

              If sh.Range("Q" & i).Value <> Empty And sh.Range("N" & i).Value <> "Designer" And sh.Range("O" & i).Value <> "Layouter" Then
              Set copyrange = sh.Range("A" & i & ":E" & i & ",I" & i & ":O" & i & ",Q" & i & ",V" & i) 'name column in sheet  = Q
              NameDevice = sh.Range("Q" & i).Value
              adressDevice = sh.Range("Q" & i)
              copyrange.Copy
              Sheets("Summary").Select

              LastRowsummary = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048555").End(xlUp).Row
              Range("B" & LastRowsummary + 1).Select
              ActiveSheet.Paste
              Range("A" & LastRowsummary + 1) = sh.Name
              Range("A" & LastRowsummary + 1, "O" & LastRowsummary + 1).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

              Sheets("Summary").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Sheets("Summary").Range("N" & LastRowsummary + 1), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sh.Name & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=NameDevice
              End If



        Next


    End If


Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("Summary").Activate

End Sub
```

***edit**: After some testing I noticed that the error is gone when I use a full range of columns instead of only some columns.

with error:

```
Set copyrange = sh.Range("A" & i & ",V" & i)
```

w/o error:

```
Set copyrange = sh.Range("A" & i & ":E" & i)
```

***second edit:**

I'm using the code from 'Tim Williams'. There was the same error. Instead of using:

```
rw.Range("A1:E1,I1:O1,Q1,V1").Copy rng.Offset(0, 1)
```

I've found a workaround. I split it up.

```
rw.Range("I1:O1").Copy rng.Offset(0, 6)
rw.Range("Q1").Copy rng.Offset(0, 13)
rw.Range("V1").Copy rng.Offset(0, 14)
```

Now this works without error. But if anyone knows what causes the problem, you may always share it. Thanks in advance.

***third edit:**

I still don't know why it doesn't work. It has something to do with range from different columns. The funny (and very frustrated part) is that I use range this way in another sheet and there I don't have this problem. It is driving me mad. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: My eyes hurt! Stop using `select` before referencing a cell with `ActiveSheet`. Try instead using `Sheets("Summary").Range("A1048555").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook` are best friends of _it works when debugging but not when running_. Follow @Gareth suggestion, get rid of `Active` stuffs and use unique references instead. You need to debug it properly, i.e. without `Active` stuffs flashing the code.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, but even when I get rid of the active stuff, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Compiled but not tested"

```
Private Sub btnGetDevices_Click()
'open every sheet after summary
'copy columns A,B,C,D,E,I,J,K,L,M,N,O, Q,V to summary

Dim sh As Worksheet, shtsumm As Worksheet
Dim copyrange As Range, arrExclude, rw As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, rng As Range
Dim NameDevice, adressDevice

    'sheets to ignore
    arrExclude = Array("Database", "Template", "Help", "OVERVIEW", _
                      "Develop", "Schedule", "Information", "Announcements", _
                      "Summary")

    Set shtsumm = Sheets("Summary")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    shtsumm.Rows(4 & ":" & shtsumm.Rows.Count).Delete
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, arrExclude, 0)) Then

            lastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 14 To lastRow

                  Set rw = sh.Rows(i)

                  If rw.Cells(1, "Q").Value <> Empty And _
                     rw.Cells(1, "N").Value <> "Designer" And _
                     rw.Cells(1, "O").Value <> "Layouter" Then

                      NameDevice = rw.Range("Q1").Value
                      adressDevice = rw.Range("Q1").Value '<<<typo ?

                      'find destination
                      Set rng = shtsumm.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

                      rng.Value = sh.Name
                      'Here Range is relative to *rw*, not to the whole sheet
                      rw.Range("A1:E1,I1:O1,Q1,V1").Copy rng.Offset(0, 1)
                      rng.Resize(1, 15).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

                      shtsumm.Hyperlinks.Add _
                         anchor:=rng.EntireRow.Cells(1, "N"), _
                         Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & sh.Name & "'!A1", _
                         TextToDisplay:=NameDevice
                  End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    shtsumm.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This code is so much cleaner than what I wrote. But I still have the same error at the same place.

Comment: @VeVi - I can run this with no problem in Excel 2010 `Sheet1.Range("A1:E1,I1:O1,Q1,V1").Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")`  What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: well, I have a very strange problem with that. At 1 page I use range like that and there is no problem. But at this page it doesn't work. I really don't understand it. I work with excel 2010.

Comment: Unless you can share your workbook there's not much more I can suggest, and in any case you seem to have a work-around.

Comment: Your help and suggestions are very much appreciated! At the moment it works, when I have some more time I'm gonna look deeper into it ;o)